# *** fatal error - error while loading shared libraries: C: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: cygwin

Windows 10.
Cygwin was working.
1.  Reinstalled cygwin64 3 times.
2.  Move it around in my system path variable and local path variables.
3.  Removed anything in the windows registry that returned from the search of the word “cygwin”.

*** fatal error - error while loading shared libraries: C: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Reinstalled cygwin64 3 times.
2.  Move it around in my system path variable and local path variables.
3.  Removed anything in the windows registry that returned from the search of the word “cygwin”.

Comment: First tell us what program you are trying to execute when you see this error message.

Comment: You are giving us too little info, and anyway it does not seem a programming question. If you have the problem with every cygwin application than the right place to receive support is the cygwin mailing list https://cygwin.com/lists.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because general support on not working Cygwin system belongs to the cygwin general mailing list https://cygwin.com/lists.html